# Angular 8 componet interaction after model close

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am in dashboard component, in the dashboard component i have a modal. In the modal I am calling another component B-Comp.After some changes in B-comp, I will close the modal and B-comp will close and now it's back on the Dashboard component. On dashboard how do i get get the B-compo data changes?

[Image of my modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPb3o.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Output()` decorator inside BComp to pass your data like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'b-component'
})
export class BComponent {
  @Output()
  public close: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public onClose() {
    this.close.emit(this.myData) 
  }
}
```

in your dashboard component

dashboard.component.html

```
<b-component (close)="onMyBComponentClose($event)"></b-component>
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
...
public onMyBComponentClose(bData) {
 console.log(bData)
}
...
```